# Creating record containing nothing but associations without explicitly setting ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code in my controller and I am trying to create a userProgram record:

```
$program = Program::find($request['program']);

$user->userProgram()->create([

]);
```

I feel like I don't explicitly have to set these values using create() if my relationships are setup properly

however, I am having trouble creating this userProgram record automatically with laravel, can anyone assist?

`userProgram` has a `program_id` and a `user_id`

UserProgram.php

```
  class UserProgram extends Model
    {
        public function User()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User');
        }

        public function Program()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Program');
        }
    }
```

Program.php

```
class Program extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['developer_id', 'name'];


    public function userProgram()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\UserProgram');
    }
}
```

Comment: How your table is linked with each other. Does userProgram is a reference to Program Model.

Comment: Yes, userProgram holds a foreign key to a program. userProgram `hasOne` program.

Comment: plz post your relationship code.

Comment: What type of relationship it is, one to one, one to  many or many to many.

Comment: See edited, I added relationship code

Comment: Users can have one UserProgram, a UserProgram can have one Program.

Comment: I guess this can be achieved by using attach `$user->userProgram()->attach($programId)` See reference link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: So if user can have only one program you can add program_id in users table instead using intermediate table. Intermediate tables are useful to store many to may relationship.

Comment: hasOne relationship doesn't have `attach()` method available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210738/discussion-between-deepak-and-anchovylegend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user create method like below.

```
$user->userProgram()->create(['program_id' => $programId]);
```